# Value does not fall within the expected range in ssis...huh?

Tags: postgresql, ssis

I'm working is SSIS and want to select a value from a function on a PostgreSQL database.  (This SSIS package retrieves data from the PostgreSQL database for processing into a data mart.  The function here is simply setting a status flag in a table on the PostgreSQL database.)

The function returns a single character ('Y' or 'N').  I am executing it with a SQL Task, issuing the statement 'select edw_processing_start_process from ;'.

The statement works, in the sense that the flag is successfully switched on the PostgreSQL database.  But the SQL Task returns the error in the title of this question.  (I've googled that error, found a lot of references, but none that seem to pertain to this precise situation...I guess it appears in a lot of Microsoft tools.)

The ResultSet of the SQL Task is set at Single row, the variable set to string data type.  Beyond that, I don't really have any idea what's going on.

Thanks,  --sw

Comment: First try capturing your return value as an object (i.e. an ADO recordset) rather than a string and see if it executes OK. Perhaps the PostgreSQL metadata definiiton of a string does not match the SSIS definition of a string. Maybe even go back a step and don't capture the result at all, just to verify that that's where the issue is.

Comment: I'm doing something similar, it was working with PGNP but with psqlodbc as the driver it fails. I'll post an answer below if I figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you were using the same driver (psqlodbc) but by some miracle I figured out that if I use "1" as the Result Name instead of the name of the returned column, it works like a charm.

Comment: Best answer of them all!

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this issue as well, changing the output external column type from DT_WSTR to DT_STR seems to have solved it for me. Not sure why it worked for years with DT_WSTR and now doesn't but hey whatever.